# Issue with header hiding animation on Flatlist scroll in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have to hide header (image) on flatlist scrolling. I have image and flatlist in different components. I am updating using flat list onscroll native event contentoffset y value to update the animation in image component. The animation is working perfectly but have an issue with a lot of space under flatlist as in Image. I have Image and flatlist component under Animated.View and the animation is applied on that Animated.View.And this Animated.View is under a View.

```
<View style={{backgroundColor:'yellow',flexDirection:'column',flex:1}}>
                <Animated.View style={[styles.container, {
                    opacity: this.state.fadeAnim, transform: [{
                        translateY: headerTranslate

                    }]
                }]}>

                    <Image style={styles.topImage} source={require('../Images/chimp.jpg')} />

                    <DashboardTabView navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate} topScrollAnimation={this.state.topScrollAnim}></DashboardTabView>

                </Animated.View>
            </View>
```

And transform code is

```
const HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT = 320;
const HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT = 70;
const HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE = HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT - HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT;

const headerTranslate = this.state.topScrollAnim.interpolate({
           inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
           outputRange: [0, -HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
           extrapolate: 'clamp',
       });
```

Please let me know what am doing wrong

[image: Before scrolling the flatlist]

[image: After scrolling, the space below the view. Flatlist is being scrolled with in that view]

[image: Video showing the issue]

[image: Differntiating flatlist and topview]

Comment: do you mean the big yellow empty space is not desired? What would you like here instead?

Comment: Yes, the big yellow space is not expected. I expect to have flatlist being displayed in that place. Flatlist is being scrolled above that view. If i give some height for the Animated.View, then i am not seeing that space. But i don't want to specify height as static value.

Comment: Posted the gif video for understanding.

Comment: have you added `flex:1` to your `FlatList` styles ?

Comment: yeah i did added flex:1